# Replace the contents of a WPF grid after a button click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, kinect

I'm trying to modify a C# Kinect sample (Kinect Fusion Explorer).

In the main window for the application, there is a grid which diplays a 3D rendering of the kinect fusion feed.

I would like to know if it would be possible to replace the contents of this grid after a clicking a button in the form.

```
<Grid x:Name="CompositeHost" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ClipToBounds="False" >
    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0">
        <Image Name="shadedSurfaceImage"/>
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewport3D Name="GraphicsViewport" IsHitTestVisible="False" >
        <!-- 3D elements are added here programatically, for performance can add the following to line above: RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"  -->
    </Viewport3D>
</Grid>
```

Right now the feed uses the ViewPort3D to output the feed. I would like to output a simple video feed after the button click. Here is what the XAML looks like for a simple video feed:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Name="videoImage"/>
</Grid>
```

I am completely new to C# and WPF development so I just wanted to know if this was achievable or whether I would have to open a completely new window to display the video feed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a project that actually uses that a lot, I need navigation between different grids. I'm using a single window and diferent pages this is a very good example of what I'm doing:
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2214/how-to-do-push-to-press-with-kinect-sdk-17
That one it's a project not made by me but basically is this:

```
<DockPanel>
        <Frame x:Name="_mainFrame"    NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
</DockPanel>
```

In this part you declare the mainFrame which is the content that will change on the windows.

```
(Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("_mainFrame") as Frame).Source = new Uri("theOtherPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

And here is the click event.

Remember using the Uri clas for loading different resources and name the mainframe you want to change.

Comment: Please provide the essence of the link in your answer. Link-only questions are not considered to be acceptable.